# How to Resize NSImage using stretching in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

I am developing photography app. In that i need to create frame for `NSImage` i have done using drawing like this

```
NSImage *fg_img = [[NSImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath]];
        //NSData *imageData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL encryptedFileURLWithPath:str]] ;
        NSImage *bg_img = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL encryptedFileURLWithPath:str]];



    NSImage *newImage ;

    NSRect imageRect = NSMakeRect(0,0, fg_img.size.width+fg_img.size.width/5, fg_img.size.height+fg_img.size.height/5);
    newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: NSMakeSize(imageRect.size.width,imageRect.size.height)];
    NSRect fgrect = NSMakeRect(imageRect.size.width*0.03,imageRect.size.height*0.04, imageRect.size.width-imageRect.size.width/15.5, imageRect.size.height-imageRect.size.height/12);

    [newImage lockFocus];

    [fg_img drawInRect:fgrect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    [bg_img drawInRect:imageRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

    [newImage unlockFocus];
```

but its not clear..

the original frame image

[image: my original frame is]

when I scaling it output is 
[image]

In above picture the width of the frame has changed when I resize frame image.
I need without changing width of frame image when scaling.

updated:

but your code display like this

[image: preview]

if i give big picture the base image become very thin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for nine part image.
The Nine part image resizes left and right side only vertically,
top and bottom only horizontally, center is resized axes independently, and corners are not resized.

```
_____________ 
|c |  hor | c|  
|__|______|__|
|  |      |  |
|v | axes |v |
|e |indep.|e |
|r |      |r |
|__|______|__|
|c |  hor |c |
|__|______|__|
```

Apple hase a method that helps you to draw such images: `NSDrawNinePartImage` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html)
But it needs images to be prepared.

The initialization code is like this:

```
    static NSImage *baseImage = NULL;
    static NSImage *topLeftCornerImage;
    static NSImage *topEdgeImage;
    static NSImage *topRightCornerImage;
    static NSImage *leftEdgeImage;
    static NSImage *centerImage;
    static NSImage *rightEdgeImage;
    static NSImage *bottomLeftCornerImage;
    static NSImage *bottomEdgeImage;
    static NSImage *bottomRightCornerImage;

    + (void)initialize;
    {
        if (baseImage) return;

        //46x46


        baseImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"badge.png"];

        topLeftCornerImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(22, 22)];
        [topLeftCornerImage lockFocus];
        [baseImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,22,22)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(0.0,24,22,22)
                    operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [topLeftCornerImage unlockFocus];

        topEdgeImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(2, 22)];
        [topEdgeImage lockFocus];
        [baseImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,2,22)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(22,24,2,22)
                    operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [topEdgeImage unlockFocus];

        topRightCornerImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(22, 22)];
        [topRightCornerImage lockFocus];
        [baseImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,22,22)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(24,24,22,22)
                    operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [topRightCornerImage unlockFocus];

        leftEdgeImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(22, 2)];
        [leftEdgeImage lockFocus];
        [baseImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,22,2)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(0,22,22,2)
                    operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [leftEdgeImage unlockFocus];

        centerImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(2, 2)];
        [centerImage lockFocus];
        [baseImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,2,2)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(22,22,2,2)
                    operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [centerImage unlockFocus];

        rightEdgeImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(22, 2)];
        [rightEdgeImage lockFocus];
        [baseImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,22,2)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(24,24,22,2)
                    operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [rightEdgeImage unlockFocus];

        bottomLeftCornerImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(22, 22)];
        [bottomLeftCornerImage lockFocus];
        [baseImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,22,22)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,22,22)
                    operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [bottomLeftCornerImage unlockFocus];

        bottomEdgeImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(2, 22)];
        [bottomEdgeImage lockFocus];
        [baseImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 2, 22)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(22, 0, 2, 22)
                    operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [bottomEdgeImage unlockFocus];

        bottomRightCornerImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(22, 22)];
        [bottomRightCornerImage lockFocus];
        [baseImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,22,22)
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(24,0,22,22)
                    operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [bottomRightCornerImage unlockFocus];
    }
```

drawingCode:

```
NSDrawNinePartImage([self bounds],
                    topLeftCornerImage, topEdgeImage, topRightCornerImage,
                    leftEdgeImage, centerImage, rightEdgeImage,
                    bottomLeftCornerImage, bottomEdgeImage, bottomRightCornerImage,
                    NSCompositeSourceOver, 1.0, NO);
```

here is another example of my realization for CALayer based nine part image - NinePartLayer.

NinePartLayer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NinePartLayer : CALayer {
@private
    NSSize _blockSize;
    NSMutableArray* layers;
    NSMutableArray* _images;
}

+ (NinePartLayer*) layerWithImage:(NSImage*)aImage;

@property (assign)NSSize blockSize;
- (void) setImage:(NSImage*)aImage;
@end
```

NinePartLayer.m

```
#import "NinePartLayer.h"

@interface NinePartLayer()

@property (retain)NSMutableArray* layers;
@property (retain)NSMutableArray* images;

@end

@implementation NinePartLayer
@synthesize images = _images;
@synthesize blockSize = _blockSize;
@synthesize layers;

+(NSImage*) imageFromImage:(NSImage *)anImage rect:(NSRect)aRect
{
    @try {
        NSPoint point = { -aRect.origin.x, -aRect.origin.y };
        NSImage *theImage = [[self alloc] initWithSize:aRect.size];
        [theImage lockFocus];
        [anImage compositeToPoint:point operation:NSCompositeCopy];
        [theImage unlockFocus];
        [theImage autorelease];
        return theImage;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[exception description]);
        return nil;
    }
}

+ (NinePartLayer*) layerWithImage:(NSImage*)aImage
{
    NinePartLayer* newLayer = [NinePartLayer layer];
    [newLayer setImage:aImage];
    return newLayer;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.layers = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.images = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) updateLayers
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 && i < [self.images count]; ++i) {
        NSMutableArray* row = [self.images objectAtIndex:i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3 && j < [row count]; ++j) {
            CALayer* item = [row objectAtIndex:j];
            float x,y,width,height;
            if(i == 0){
                y = 0;
                height = floorf(self.blockSize.height);
            } else if(i == 1){
                y = ceilf(self.blockSize.height);      
                height = self.frame.size.height - 2*self.blockSize.height;
            } else if(i == 2){
                y = self.frame.size.height - self.blockSize.height;
                height = self.blockSize.height;
            };
            if(j == 0){
                x = 0;
                width = self.blockSize.width;
            } else if(j == 1){
                x = self.blockSize.width;
                width = self.frame.size.width - 2*self.blockSize.width;
            } else if(j == 2){
                x = self.frame.size.width - self.blockSize.width;
                width = self.blockSize.width;
            };

            item.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

            float delta=0;

            if((i==1)&&(j==0))
            {
                item.frame = CGRectMake(x, y-delta, width+delta, height+2*delta);
            }

            if((i==2)&&(j==1))
            {
                item.frame = CGRectMake(x-delta, y-delta, width+2*delta, height+delta);
            }

            if((i==1)&&(j==2))
            {
                item.frame = CGRectMake(x-delta, y-delta, width+delta, height+2*delta);
            }

            if((i==0)&&(j==1))
            {
                item.frame = CGRectMake(x-delta, y, width+2*delta, height+delta);
            }
        }
    } 
}

- (void) setImage:(NSImage*)aImage
{
   for(int i = 0; i < [self.layers count]; ++i)
        [[self.layers objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperlayer];

    [self.layers removeAllObjects];

    self.images = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.layers = [NSMutableArray array];
    if(!aImage)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        NSMutableArray* row = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            NSImage* img = [NSImage imageFromImage:aImage 
                                              rect:NSMakeRect((float)j/3.0*[aImage size].width, 
                                                              (float)i/3.0*[aImage size].height, 
                                                              1.0/3.0*[aImage size].width,
                                                              1.0/3.0*[aImage size].height)];
            self.blockSize = NSMakeSize(1.0/3.0*[aImage size].width, 1.0/3.0*[aImage size].height);

            CALayer* item = [CALayer layer];
            [item performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setContents:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:NO];
            [item performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setContentsGravity:) withObject:kCAGravityResize waitUntilDone:NO];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSublayer:) withObject:item waitUntilDone:NO];
            [row addObject:item];
            [self.layers addObject:item];
        }
        [self.images addObject:row];
    }
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLayers) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    [self updateLayers];
}

- (void) setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    [super setBounds:bounds];
    [self updateLayers];
}

- (void) setPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    [super setPosition:position];
    [self updateLayers];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.layers = nil;
    self.images = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

usage:

```
    NinePartLayer * pageContainerShadowlayer=[NinePartLayer layerWithImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"drop_shadow.png"]];
    pageContainerShadowlayer.frame=[mainView layer].bounds;
    pageContainerShadowlayer.autoresizingMask=kCALayerWidthSizable | kCALayerHeightSizable;
    [[rootView layer] insertSublayer:pageContainerShadowlayer atIndex:3];
```

Comment: I think you have error in images initialization. Try to recheck sizes. i used this image in example  http://froggyproggy.com/tmp/badge.png

Comment: Maybe your original image is low resolution? The code draws it pixel to pixel. not scaled.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbled on this question years later (like I did) – starting in macOS 10.10 (Yosemite), NSImage has a `capInsets` property which takes care of the nine-part image behaviour using a single source image.  Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [NSDrawNinePartImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDrawNinePartImage)? It's a function designed specifically for drawing nine images (four corners, four edges, and a center) in the arrangement you propose, without visible seams and without stretching the corner and edge images.

Comment: it dross the center tiled though IIRC.. or stretched.. it cannot do one or the other though :D

Comment: Ah, yes—NSDrawNinePartImage tiles the center image. No stretching it to fit the frame. It could still work, but only if the questioner computes the frame size around the size of the image and will never want to scale it up or down.