# How to resize image while preserving edges / details in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, image-resizing

I'm making a game in `Swift` using `SpriteKit` and I'm running into a problem when making the UI. lots of my UI elements are rectangles, while my source images are squares, so when I resize them the images stretch the details in one dimension more than the other.

Here is an example:

[image: Original Image]

Turns Into

[image: This]

However, I want to make the images larger, different shaped rectangle but have the details stay the same proportion but also size. I don't want the little triangles to size up and the outline stay the same thickness.

Taken from sample use of UI sprites:

[image: Taken from sample use of UI sprites]

Note: This is being made for MacOS

I tried using `NSEdgeInsets` but either they are not what Im looking for or I couldn't get them to work, as there isn't a lot of useful documentation online that I could find.

Comment: You may find using nine part image stretching is what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647510/how-to-resize-nsimage-using-stretching-in-cocoa .